# C# WPF Window creation

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a WPF project based on C#. 
While working on my project, I have ran into some troubles in how to create a single instance window (Like if i want to open the window X, it cannot be opened again unless it is closed). I found many articles online but they seemed lika lot of work, that it seemed easier to just disable the button when the window is open and enable it when the window is closed.

On the other hand I thought of an alternative solution which worked, but I want to see if it will be heavy on my system when a lot of windows are created.

The solution is shown below.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Window1 wndw = new Window1();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           if (!wndw.IsActive)
            wndw.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, i created the window at the start, and when the button to open it is clicked, it checks if it is active or not to show.

If I follow the latter method, will all the windows be loaded on MainWindow creation, or will the components only load when the event window1.show() is launched?

Thank you for your support

Comment: Dear, the button is located in the main window which is shown. When it is clicked, the new window called here wndw of type Window1 will open. My problem is that if i use wndw.show(), I can go back to the mainwindow and press the button again, which will open another new wndw of type Window1

Comment: Umm, normally you would just overload the Close event and hide the window instead of allowing it to be closed.

Comment: i added a global boolean parameter in the properties settings tab, which will be true if the window is open. If this parameter is true the window will not open. On windows close event i set it to false. The only downside is that for each different window i need to create a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would have done it:

**MainWindow code:**

```
Window1 window1 = null; // global reference var

private void btnOpenWin1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (window1 == null)
    {
        window1 = new Window1();
        window1.Closed += Window1_Closed; // register event to detect when Window1 closed
        window1.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        window1.Focus();
    }
}

// register event to remove Window1 ref to be able to open it again
private void Window1_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    window1 = null;
}
```